# Creating a column of count in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to quickly add a column that counts the number of repetitions of [user, class] group.

For example;

```
user    class   val
1   2   23
1   2   23
1   3   29
1   3   29
1   4   11
```

The code groupby `user` and `class` and create a column that ranges from 1 (or 0) to the number of occurence of that group.

```
user    class   Mean    n_count
1   2   23  1
1   2   23  2
1   3   29  1
1   3   29  2
1   4   11  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and then [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
>>> df["n_count"] = df.groupby(["user", "class"]).cumcount() + 1
>>> df
   user  class  val  n_count
0     1      2   23        1
1     1      2   23        2
2     1      3   29        1
3     1      3   29        2
4     1      4   11        1
```